# Group By Largest revision string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to figure out a way to group these properly. I have a results set that returns Incident numbers which are actually datatype string, that have revisions done. I only need the grouping of the last revision number entered. Such as the below.

```
INC-101
INC-101
INC-101A1
INC-101A1
INC-101A2
INC-101A2
JNC-101
JNC-101
JNC-101S1
JNC-101S1
```

How could I only see the highest revision number such as the following:

```
INC-101A2
INC-101A2
JNC-101S1
JNC-101S1
```

Comment: Group by incident number, order by incident number, and select the top 1.

Comment: Store the revision separately

Comment: .. or if you can't split it (substring, or something), so that you can group it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `SUBSTRING`, e.g.:

```
SELECT MAX(incident_no)
FROM incidents
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(incident_no, 1, 7);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ada49d/1/0)**.

**Update**

If you want all the rows belonging to the latest revision number then you can use the above query as sub-query, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM incidents
WHERE incident_no IN (
    SELECT MAX(incident_no)
    FROM incidents
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(incident_no, 1, 7)
);
```

Comment: When the query returns multiple rows of the same number I need all those rows. Here is the updated SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fb226/1 I need all rows of Incident numbers that are the same, but just need the largest group.

Comment: so I just noticed is the length of my incident numbers are different it doesn't group properly so the substring(1,7) isn't working. Anyway to make this work with any length of Incident number?

Comment: Do you have any format for incident numbers? Might need to use `regex` for that.

Comment: Looks like I was able to make your query work by using `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(incident_no, 1, len(incident_no)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `max`-function in conjunction with group by on the "base" of an incident numner. Not sure, if it works completely as you expect, since I do not know the number system used. But maybe with some adaptions you get the results you want rather easy:

```
select max(incnumber)
from incidents
group by left(incnumber,7)
```